# Query relationship with v-autocomplete in Vuetify [ Laravel ]

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I use dropdown `v-autocomplete` in `Vuetify` and i want to query `relationship`  from `laravel`. When select in input field in `v-autocomplete`, its work well, its show name that i want to query, but when i `selected` on it, it show to `default value`.

**Here my Vuetify**

```
    <template>
        <v-autocomplete
          :items="purchases"
          dense
          solo
          v-model="model"
          item-text="name"
          item-value="name"
          return-object
          clearable
          @input="addTocart"
        >
            <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
                {{ item.product.name }}
            </template>
        </v-autocomplete>
      </template>
```

**In my script**

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Add Purchase',
        created() {
            this.fetchPurchase()
        },

        data() {
            return {
                products: [],
                purchases: [],
                model: [],
                items: [],
                purchase_status: ['Received', 'Partial', 'Pending', 'Ordered'],
                discount: 0.00,
                tax: 0.00,
                shipping_cost: 0.00,
            }
        },

        computed: {
            total() {
                return this.products.reduce((total, item) => {
                    return total + item.unit;
                }, 0);
            }
        },

        methods: {

            fetchPurchase() {
                this.$axios.$get(`api/purchase`)
                .then(res => {
                    this.purchases = res.data;
                    console.log(res);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            },

            addTocart (item) {
                if(this.items.includes(item)) {
                    alert("already there");
                }else {
                    this.items.push(item);
                }

                item.unit = 1;
            },

            removeItem(index) {
                this.items.splice(index, 1)
            },  


        }
    }
</script>
```

Is there a way that i can archieve this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Could you please post sample of purchases items?